# Why does my computer freeze when I run the command `airmon-ng start wlan0`

Tags: command-line, airmon-ng

Yeah.. Sure bro.. I'll make more clear I think. 
Why does my computer freeze when I run the command `airmon-ng start wlan0`?

It outputs

> Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
>   If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
>   a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
>
> PID Name
>     698 avahi-daemon
>     702 avahi-daemon
>     744 NetworkManager
>     782 wpa_supplicant
>    1188 dhclient
>
> PHY      Interface Driver      Chipset
>
> phy0   wlan0       wl      Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

Comment: Random guess, but does the wireless chip support passive mode? Can you [edit] your question and add the manufacturer and the model of the chip?

Comment: Happens the same here, BCM4360 802.11ac (rev 03), I have a Macbook.